# scroll up/down when button is hold clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

please check , i want that content should be scrolled up/ down ,event when text is hold clicked 
http://liveweave.com/0m3zQQ

```
(function () {
    var scrolled = 10;
    $('#scrollup').click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-menu").animate({
    scrollTop:  $(".sidebar-menu").scrollTop() - scrolled
    });
  });


    $('#scrolldown').click(function() {
    $(".sidebar-menu").animate({
    scrollTop:  $(".sidebar-menu").scrollTop() + scrolled
    });
  });

})();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use combination of `mousedown` and `mouseup` events:

```
$('#scrollup').on({
    'mousedown touchstart': function () {
        $(".sidebar-menu").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000);
    },
    'mouseup touchend': function () {
        $(".sidebar-menu").stop(true);
    }
});

$('#scrolldown').on({
    'mousedown touchstart': function () {
        $(".sidebar-menu").animate({
            scrollTop: $(".sidebar-menu")[0].scrollHeight
        }, 2000);
    },
    'mouseup touchend': function () {
        $(".sidebar-menu").stop(true);
    }
});
```

Also added touch events.

#### Demo: http://liveweave.com/j73xMq

Comment: Because on tablet there are no mouse events. Try this then `$('#scrollup').on('mousedown touchstart', function() {}).on('mouseup touchend', function() {})`.

Comment: i notice when i do it in mobile i see it works fine, but after few seconds text selection option to copy text appears how to remove it

Comment: Try to add `return false` to `mousedown touchstart` handler.

Comment: how ? and where can u give excat line

Comment: Make it the last line of `'mousedown touchstart'` function.

Comment: Like this: `'mousedown touchstart': function () { $(".sidebar-menu").animate({scrollTop: 0}, 2000); return false; },`

Comment: That's brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this by using [mousedown event](http://api.jquery.com/mousedown/)
Change your 'click' handler to 'mousedown' in below way

```
$('#scrollup').on("mousedown",function() {
```